# How to insert characters from one column that follow a pattern to another column?

Tags: r, search

Let's say I have a dataset that looks something like this.

```
                Name  Time
ABC_something_month1    NA
ABD_something_month2    NA
ABD_something_month1    NA
```

How would I write a code that searches for 'month' and inserts the following number in the column Time so that it looks like this

```
                Name  Time
ABC_something_month1     1
ABD_something_month2     2
ABD_something_month1     1
```

Comment: how about this?  `name<-c("ABC_something_month1", "ABC_something_month2",  "ABC_something_month1")`
`gsub("[^0-9.]", "", name) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the number following `"month"`

```
df$Time <- sub('.*month(\\d+)', '\\1', df$Name)
df
#                  Name Time
#1 ABC_something_month1    1
#2 ABD_something_month2    2
#3 ABD_something_month1    1
```

Or using `str_extract` :

```
df$Time <- stringr::str_extract(df$Name, '(?<=month)\\d+')
```

Comment: oh thanks, just one more thing. 
if the name is actually ```ABD_something_month1.something``` , how would I make sure it doesn't add the ```.something ```.

Comment: @strkiky2 In that case you can use `sub('.*month(\\d+).*', '\\1', df$Name)`

Comment: Can I ask what the ```(\\d+)``` and ```\\1``` mean?

Comment: `\\d` means a number and `\\d+` means more than 1 number. We capture it using backreference (`\\1`). You can read more about it in `?sub`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Time = parse_number(Name))
```

---

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
    mutate(Time = str_remove_all(Name, "\\D+"))
```